# vueI18n configuration problems with vue3 and JEST 27

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jestjs, vue-i18n

Since my project underwent a migration from vue2 to vue3, i have some issues with the JEST test, especially with vueI18n.

I have this configuration:

package.json

```
    "vue": "^3.3.4",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.4.0",
    "vue-i18n-jest": "^1.1.1",
    "jest": "^27.1.0",
```

i18n configuration:

```
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n';

import en from '@/locales/en.json';
import es from '@/locales/es.json';
import fr from '@/locales/fr.json';
import it from '@/locales/it.json';
import pt from '@/locales/pt.json';
import enZA from '@/locales/en-za.json';

import { DATE_TIME_FORMATS } from './date-time-formats';
import { NUMBER_FORMATS } from './number-formats';
import { SupportedLocale } from './supported-locale';

type MessageSchema = typeof en;

const vueI18n = createI18n<MessageSchema, SupportedLocale>({
  locale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_LOCALE || 'en',
  fallbackLocale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_FALLBACK_LOCALE || 'en',
  messages: {
    en,
    fr,
    es,
    it,
    pt,
    'en-ZA': enZA
  },
  numberFormats: NUMBER_FORMATS,
  datetimeFormats: DATE_TIME_FORMATS,
  legacy: false,

  fallbackWarn: false,
  missingWarn: false
});

export default vueI18n;
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  preset: '@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/typescript-and-babel',
  collectCoverageFrom: ['**/src/**/!(main.ts|router.ts|routes.ts)', '!**/plugins/**/*.ts', '!**/*.json'],
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'jsx',
    'json',
    'vue',
    'ts',
    'tsx',
    'mjs'
  ],
  transform: {
    'vue-i18n': 'vue-i18n-jest',
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest',
    '.*\\.(vue)$': '@vue/vue3-jest',
    '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|svg|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$': 'jest-transform-stub',
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest'
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules',
    '/node_modules/(?!vuetify/)',
    '/node_modules/(?!vuetify/*)',
    '/node_modules/(?!vuetify)'
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
    vuetify: '<rootDir>/node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js',
    useI18n: '<rootDir>/node_modules/vue-i18n/dist/vue-18n.mjs',
    '\\.(css|less)$': 'identity-obj-proxy'
  },
  silent: true,
  snapshotSerializers: [
    'jest-serializer-vue'
  ],
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  testMatch: [
    '**/tests/unit/**/*.(spec|test).(js|jsx|ts|tsx)|**/__tests__/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'
  ],
  testURL: 'http://localhost/',
  watchPlugins: [
    'jest-watch-typeahead/filename',
    'jest-watch-typeahead/testname'
  ],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      babelConfig: true
    }
  },
  automock: false,
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/tests/setupTests.ts'],
  maxWorkers: 2
};
```

i'm encountering some issues like this:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'locale')`

for reading: `i18n.global`

or like this:

```
    SyntaxError: Need to install with `app.use` function

      153 |
      154 |   setup() {
    > 155 |     const { t } = useI18n();
```

I need to know how to configure jest for use with i18n, i've tried many many different configuration without find the good one.

I precise the code work good, only the tests are broken.

thx